# Error using choice from random module in Python

Tags: python, random, error-handling

I'm trying to build a randomized dataset based on an input dataset.
The input dataset consists of 856471 lines, and in each line there is a pair of values separated by a tab.
NO entry from the randomized dataset can be equal to any of those in the input dataset, this means:

If the pair in line 1 is "Protein1    Protein2", the randomized dataset cannot contain the following pairs:

- "Protein1    Protein2"
- "Protein2    Protein1"

In order to achieve this I tried the following:

```
data = infile.readlines()
ltotal = len(data)
for line in data:
    words = string.split(line)

init = 0
while init != ltotal:
    p1 = random.choice(words)
    p2 = random.choice(words)
    words.remove(p1)
    words.remove(p2)
    if "%s\t%s\n" % (p1, p2) not in data and "%s\t%s\n" % (p2, p1) not in data:
        outfile.write("%s\t%s\n" % (p1, p2))
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\eduarte\Desktop\negcreator.py", line 46, in <module>
    convert(indir, outdir)   File "C:\Users\eduarte\Desktop\negcreator.py", line 27, in convert
    p1 = random.choice(words)   File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 274, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I was pretty sure this would work. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `words` is overwritten for each line in the loop

```
for line in data:
    words = string.split(line)
```

This is most probably not what you want.

Moreover, your `while` loop is an infinite loop, which will consume `words` eventually, leaving no choices for `random.choice()`.

**Edit**: My guess is that you have a file of tab-separated word pairs, a pair in each line, and you are trying to form random pairs from all of the words, writing only those random pairs to the output file that do not occur in the original file.  Here is some code doing this:

```
import itertools
import random
with open("infile") as infile:
    pairs = set(frozenset(line.split()) for line in infile)
words = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(pairs))
random.shuffle(words)
with open("outfille", "w") as outfile:
    for pair in itertools.izip(*[iter(words)] * 2):
        if frozenset(pair) not in pairs:
            outfile.write("%s\t%s\n" % pair)
```

Notes:

1. A pair of words is represented by a `frozenset`, since order does not matter.
2. I use a `set` for all the pairs to be able to test if a pair is in the set in constant time.
3. Instead of using `random.choice()` repeatedly, I only shuffle the whole list once, and then iterate over it in pairs.  This way, we don't need to remove the already used words from the list, so it's much more efficient.  (This change an the previous one bring down the algorithmic complexity of the approach from O(n²) to O(n).)
4. The  expression `itertools.izip(*[iter(words)] * 2)` is a common Python idiom to iterate over `words` in pairs, in case you did not encounter that one yet.
5. The code is still untested.

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the late answer. Yes, that line was really silly.
But even though I applied your suggestions and worked around them a little bit, I still couldn't make it work. EDIT: Oh, and it doesn't work in the way I get the same error I was getting in the first place.

Comment: @EdwardCoelho: It was not really clear to me what your code is actually supposed to do.  I think I got it now, and added a new version of the code.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought my explanation was good enough. Guess I don't think like a programmer yet. But yes, you got what I was thinking, that's amazing! Also it works really faster now. Just two notes: the `frozenset(pair)` should not be in `pais`, and I already got over that. Other thing, how do you limit the total number of pairs generated? I want to have the same number of lines in both files. I used `len()` to get the total lines in infile, but even using a if statement nothing changes.

Comment: @EdwardCoelho: Yes, of yourse it should be `not in pairs`, and you did say so before.

Comment: @EdwardCoelho: Changing the algorithm in order to get the same number of lines in the output file is not easy (assuming you are not allowed to change the number of occurrences of each protein).  It's actually an interesting problem, but I don't have the time to think about it right now.  I suggest to ask a new question about the basic algorithmic approach, because that is unrelated to what this question originally was.  Make sure to specify in the new question whether the proteins can occur multiple times.  And tag it "algorithm", so the algorithm crowd is looking.